# ERROR 1064 (42000) ... 'ACCOUNT LOCK' at line 1

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to lock one account and doing a simple command:

```
ALTER USER 'user_name'@'localhost' ACCOUNT LOCK;
```

And I getting such error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ACCOUNT LOCK' at line 1
```

What am I doing wrong? Using 5.6.51 MySQL

Comment: The `ACCOUNT LOCK` option is not implemented in MySQL 5.6. You need to upgrade at least to 5.7 to get that option. You should upgrade anyway, because 5.6 reached its end of life in February 2021.

Comment: Dear @BillKarwin but do you have any advise of how could I suspend user in my MYSQL version?

Comment: With all due respect, this is like asking an electrician, "I know I shouldn't stuff my electrical circuit panel with oily rags, but if I needed to, what's a good way of doing that?"

Comment: *how could I suspend user in my MYSQL version?* Simply set random password to this account and do not store it - and nobody can log in using it. When you need to make it active again then you'd set known password (maybe use old one).